# Rabin-Karp String Matching Algorithm efficiency

Tags: algorithm, performance, hash, big-o, rabin-karp

I know how the Rabin-Karp String Matching Algorithm works however not able to understand how its better than native method. In Rabin-Karp you find hash for every substring in a string and compare it with hash value of test string.And if it matches, you now compare the individual characters.However in native method, you just comapare the substring with the test string character by character. Isnt calculating the hash unnecessary and how is it faster than comparing individual characters?

Comment: [Rabin-Karp uses a rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash#Polynomial_rolling_hash). So all that's needed is to remove one character and, add one character, to move to the next position.

Comment: yeah but you can compare the substring in the same fashion. removing the first charcter from substring and adding next character to substring

Answer (score 0):

The hash is shorter than the string, possibly just one byte. If, for example, you make it by modulo 251 (highest prime number in 0-255 range), you make only a single byte comparison 99.6% of times if the compared strings are different.